# javascript string localization in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, localization, internationalization

I'm having problems with the encoding of some localized strings in laravel.

In my localization file for Spanish I have (among many other strings):

```
"truck" => "camión"
```

In myView.blade.php, if I print the string directly:

```
<h2>{{trans('localizationFile.truck'}}</h2>
```

It works fine and prints 

### camión

But if I try to use that same string in javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{           
    alert("{{trans('events.camion')}}");
}
</script>
```

It codifies the accented o and the alert reads: **`cami&oacute;n`**

How can I fix that?
Or am I doing something wrong?
Perhaps that's not the way to localize javascript messages...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When outputting an alert, the HTML entities are not decoded so they are show as plain text. The simplest solution to fix this is to add the text to an HTML element and return its content via the `text` method, which will decode the HTML entities:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert($('<div>{{trans('events.camion')}}</div>').text());
    }
</script>
```

The above uses jQuery's `html` method, but this can be achieved with vanilla JS and `innerHtml`.

---

If you want to include an extra JS library you can use [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he), that takes care of decoding. So it would look something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert(he.decode({{trans('events.camion')}}));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hum.. I thought about "saving" the text in html entities but looked too complicated. I think I'll go with the library, looks much cleaner. Thanks a lot!